# Set path for linter in setting.json [vscode]

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code

I have the following setting.json file inside the .vscode folder,

```
{
    "cSpell.ignoreWords": [
        "pformat"
    ]
}
```

I am having a problem with my eslint plugin which gives the following error in vscode,

```
[Info  - 13:14:45] Failed to load plugin 'react-hooks' declared in 'projectmt'/.eslintrc.json': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react-hooks'
```

To fix this I need to add something that specifies the path to the linting file in the project I was told but not shown how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this myself,

You need to specify in settings.json where the eslint.json file is. The code is

```
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [
    "./projectmt/"
]
```

This got my linter working in vscode again, hope this helps someone in the future.